# Is datalog more efficient than SQL for column oriented databases?

Tags: sql, clojure, datomic, datalog, cascalog

Both [Cascalog](http://cascalog.org/) and [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) have chosen to use [Datalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog) (over [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)) as their query engine.

[Dave Thomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Thomas_(software_developer)) made the claim:

> Datalog is better than SQL for large queries in small amounts of space.

My question is: **Is datalog more efficient than SQL for [column oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)?**

Comment: Datalog is not an engine. It's a language for expressing a query. How efficient it is at expressing a query bears *no* relationship to how fast an engine might be at executing that query.